# Can a script imported by a Web-Worker in turn import another script?

Tags: javascript, import, web-worker

The pattern for a script used by a webworker https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers is:

- `webworker.js`

  ```
  importScripts('./parent.js')
  ```
- `parent.js`

  ```
  import { PerfManager} from "./child.js";
  ```

The `child.js` import results in:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Is there any way to implement an import within the `parent.js` when used by `webworker.js` ?

Comment: if you want to use import instead of importScripts you need to use babel to compile parent.js and then use importScript('./compile.parent.js')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start a [module Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker) (currently only available in Blink based browsers).

```
const worker = new Worker("worker.js", { type: "module" });
```

Then instead of `importScripts` you will directly `import` *parent.js*  from this worker script, which will in turn be able to import whatever dependency.

Since StackSnippets are in null-origined iframes, I have to outsource the demo to this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/yGxaIebN8ctNRcco?open=lib%2Fscript.js).

---

Note that in these browsers you could even use the dynamic `import()` statement from *parent.js* even in a non module Worker: [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/wtYlV6tBY24QWQAu?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview), but **this still wouldn't work in browsers that don't support module Workers**.
For these you need to use only non module scripts and to use `importScripts` and its globals all along the chain: [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/1Rj3Jn2fF6FavlYD?open=lib%2Fscript.js).

Comment: I'm on `chrome`: it does support `module workers` and in fact we are using them now. But the transient dependencies are not being accepted - at least not in Intellij. Is that then IJ being too picky?

Comment: Might be indeed, I really don't know this IDE, but it should work as demonstrated in the plunkers;.